# How to use Drawer menu and bottom tab menu together in Expo Router?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, expo-router

I'm a newbie in react native.I'm working on an Expo project where I have a file structure like this:
[File Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr6DT.png)

In (drawer)/_layout.js, I have successfully added the "Home" menu from (tabs) to the Drawer menu using Expo Router, like this:

```
import { Drawer } from "expo-router/drawer";

export default function DrawerLayout() {
    return (
        <Drawer screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, drawerPosition: "right" }}>
            <Drawer.Screen 
                name="(tabs)"
                options={{
                    drawerLabel: "Home",
                    title: "Home"
                }}
            />
        </Drawer>
    );
}
```

Now, I want to add the "Latest" and "Shows" menus from (tabs) to the Drawer menu as well. How can I achieve this in (drawer)/_layout.js? What changes do I need to make to the code? Additionally, I'm using Tabs navigation in (tabs)/_layout.js,

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I tried adding drawer,screens by  (tabs)/latest ,(tabs)/Shows it's not working.